# Joomla module get current article title

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to build a module that should show the article title of the current article viewed.

I've started from this code in my default.php layout that shows the title of the page, but I need to edit it so that it shows the article title and not the page title.

```
$heading = $document->getTitle();
```

How should I edit it to get the article title instead of the page title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this way:

```
$option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
$view = JRequest::getCmd('view');
if ($option=="com_content" && $view=="article") {
    $ids = explode(':',JRequest::getString('id'));
    $article_id = $ids[0];
    $article =& JTable::getInstance("content");
    $article->load($article_id);

    $heading = $article->get("title");
}
```

Not sure it's the correct/best solution, but it seems work at the moment.
Any suggestion, comment about this code or better implementation?

Comment: If for some reason you like to go with `getString` and `explode` instead of the suggested `getInt`, it is probably a good idea to make sure `$article_id` is an integer, so I'd replace the fifth line with `$article_id = (int)$ids[0];`

Answer (score 3):

If this is in the normal article view, the following should work:

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$id = $input->getInt('id', 0);
if(
  $id > 0 
  && $input->getString('option') == 'com_content' 
  && $input->getString('view') == 'article'
) {
    $c = JTable::getInstance('content'); 
    $c->load($id);
    echo $c->title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks jonasfh for reply. Any idea also on how I can get the url for the article intro image and also for the article intro image alternative text?

Comment: Should be similar, using `$c->image_intro` and `$c->image_intro_alt`.

Comment: Use `print_r($c);` to see which properties are loaded into the content object